# How can I make my cursor unfrozen?

Tags: 20.04, mouse, touchpad, lenovo, cursor

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and my cursor worked fine, then suddenly it wouldn't move nearly every time I booted it. One thing that I found that fixed it was pressing F6 twice, but once the icon that showed you that the touchpad is enabled came up, it stopped working. I did a bunch of research and I can't figure out what is wrong or how to fix it, so I decided to reimage my computer (there was nothing I cared about on the computer, so I didn't back anything up). That helped, but I got the exact same problem a couple of weeks later. The cursor always moves when I am using a mouse instead of the touchpad. Nothing else is ever freezing, just the cursor when using the touchpad. It is also like this at the login screen, so I doubt it is settings on my profile. So far the only thing I have done is checked if zoom was enabled, which it wasn't. Any clue what is wrong? I am not sure if this matters, but the laptop I am using is Lenovo Ideapad 130S-11IGM. If you need any more information, just let me know and I will give it to you.

Comment: Sounds like it could be one of the following: 1) touchpad needs a driver, 2) touchpad needs to be enabled by hardware switch (ex. F6), 3) touchpad has a hardware issue, 4) a bug that needs to be patched.  We can't do much about #3 and #4 other than getting repairs & reporting the bug, but you should research further on #1 & #2.  What is the model of the touchpad hardware on your laptop?

Comment: @Nmath do you know how I can check?

Comment: #1 determine the model of the touchpad hardware by reviewing the documentation for your laptop and search for an up-to-date Linux driver; #2 read the documentation for your laptop to determine if and how the touchpad is enabled and disabled by a hardware switch or key shortcut